# I'm trying to create a map with a key of location that has a list of doubles as coordinates but I'm getting an error

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart, maps

I'm trying to create a sign up model and send it to my API but the "location" Key has another map/jsonobject that contains a "type": "point" and "coordinates": [double, double].

The final json object is supposed to look something like this

```
{
    "name": "Arsh Bansal",
    "email": "ab@yahoo.com",
    "password": "123456789",
    "birthday": "06-21-2000",
    "gender": "Male",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point", 
        "coordinates": [13.0987, 88.403]
    },
    "phone_number": "123456789"
}
```

The error I get is :
*Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, List>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast*

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
class Location {
  String type;
  List<double> coordinates;

  Location({this.type, this.coordinates});

  Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    type = json['type'];
    coordinates = json['coordinates'].cast<double>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['coordinates'] = this.coordinates;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: It still gives the same error i.e. Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: can you show the code where are fetching or showing these values ?

Comment: I've edited the initial question and added the fetching of the value from the signup page.